# How to protect pattern or subexpression when distributing / expanding expression?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I've got an expression like

```
expr = (1-x)(a+b)
```

that I would like to distribute / expand while keeping factors of `(1-x)` intact, i.e. the result should in the above example should look like

```
(1-x)a + (1-x)b
```

I know that for the explicit example given here, `Expand[expr,(a+b)]` would yield the desired result. However, I would need a solution where `(a+b)` can be any arbitrary algebraic expressions that is distributed with `(1-x)` being left untouched.

Is there maybe a way to define a pattern that matches my `(1-x)` terms that I can than hold while distributing?

Comment: `HoldForm[1-x](a+b) // Expand`?

Comment: Yes, but for an already existing expression (that is somewhat more complicated than my example) - how do I tell Mathematica to hold all occurrences of `(1-x)`?

Comment: Again, look up `HoldForm[]`. And while you're at it, `Defer[]` too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does `expr /. (1-x) -> HoldForm[1-x]` work? That should `Hold` all occurences of `(1-x)` in your expression.

Comment: provided you remember to do Expand afterwards ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of substituting the (1-x) term with its HoldForm variant..

Answer (score 6):

We could substitute a variable for the expression we wish to preserve, expand the result, and then substitute the expression back for the variable.  Like so:

```
expandExcept[expr_, exception_] :=
  Module[{u}, Expand[expr /. exception -> u] /. u -> exception]

expandExcept[(1-x)(a+b), 1-x]
(* a (1-x) + b (1-x) *)

expandExcept[(1-x)/(a+b)+(1-x)^2(c+d)^3, 1-x]
(* (1-x)/(a+b) + c^3 (1-x)^2 + 3 c^2 d (1-x)^2 + 3 c d^2 (1-x)^2 + d^3 (1-x)^2 *)
```

This has the advantage over a solution based upon `HoldForm` in that the result remains a valid algebraic expression.

Comment: ...and by using a formal variable like `\[FormalU]`, one could skip the use of `Module[]` in `expandExcept[]`...